# Show $\iint xye^{-xy}\,dx\,dy$ is convergent or divergent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

> Determine convergence/divergence of $$\iint xye^{-xy}\,dx\,dy$$ for $x,y \geqslant 0$ i.e. in the first quadrant.

I have managed to show that $xye^{-xy} \to 0$ in the first quadrant but other than that not gotten very much far unfortunately.

One thought I had was to use polar coordinates and for some radius $r_0$ approximate $xye^{-xy} \thicksim e^{-xy} $. I would then want to investigate $$ \iint e^{-xy} \,dx\,dy$$
in the first quadrant from radius $r_0$ to infinity (the angle lies between zero and $\pi/2$). However that integral was no more easier than the previous one.

Thoughts?

Comment: it can be done with polar, I don't know what you mean by $xye^{-xy}\sim e^{-xy}$, but see my answer below.

Comment: All you really need to do is integrate by parts you end up having to integrate $1/y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polar coordinates work, making the shift we get:

$${1\over 2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\infty r^3\sin(2\theta)e^{-r^2\sin(2\theta)/2}\,dr\,d\theta$$

Now make the $u$-substitution $u={r^2\over 2}\,du=rdr$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(2\theta)\int_0^\infty ue^{-u\sin(2\theta)}\,du\,d\theta$$

Integrating by parts, we get the $u$ terms integrate to:

$$\bigg(-\csc^2(2\theta)e^{-u\sin(2\theta)}-u\csc(2\theta)e^{-u\sin(2\theta)}\bigg|_0^\infty=-\csc^2(2\theta).$$

hence our integral reduces to

$$-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(2\theta)\left(\csc^2(2\theta)\right)\,d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2}\csc(2\theta)\,d\theta$$

And $\csc(2\theta)$ is not Riemann integrable on that interval (it is unbounded).